# How to add a parameter to the ArcGIS WebAppBuilder Search widget?

Tags: geocoding, widget, arcgis-web-appbuilder

ArcGIS WebAppBuilder (developer edition) comes with a built-in Search widget which uses the default ArcGIS world geocoder. I want to restrict the type of suggestions which are returned.

[image]

The Search widget has some configuration options, eg the ability restrict the search country (`&searchCountry`) and the number of results returned (`&maxSuggestions`). These parameters are appended to the search query, eg:

https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest?f=json&text=windsor&maxSuggestions=6&countryCode=AU

How can I edit the Search widget to allow additional parameters to be included, eg [&category=city](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-category-filtering.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_502B3FE2028145D7B189C25B1A00E17B)? This will require a new parameter on the HTML page:

[image]

... and for the query to have additional parameters appended:

https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest?f=json&text=windsor&maxSuggestions=6&countryCode=AU&category=city

The above URL returns the correct results but I can't see where in the Search Widget JS/HTML I should be making the change to add this parameter.

Comment: If you're using Widget.js, in WAB Developer Edition version 2.11, the locator is created on line 210, within _convertConfig.  You might have luck using the documentation on the ArcGIS for Developers website here:  https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/search-amd.html#sources